# How to say 'striped' in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, word-request

I'm looking for a way to describe striped cloth — that is, with regular stripes all over, or like the stripes on the flag of the USA.

I'm well aware of the stripe on a toga, *angusticlavus*, etc. But is it appropriate to use *clavus* in the general sense, or is there a better word? I have considered *striatum*, but am not sure that I'm exactly on the right track. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: ***"Varium** nunc transgrediamur **virum** . et postea Marcus in trianguli primo angulo ..."*

Comment: Yes; I'll probably have to settle for _varius_, or something similar, though it seems to mean any sort of variation, not just 'striped'. I put forward _striatus_, meaning 'fluted' as on architectural columns, but this also doesn't really convey the meaning, either. Maybe I'll just have to rely on context.

Answer (score 11):

My dictionary offers four options for "striped":

- [**Virgatus**](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=virgatus&filter=CUTF8) "striped" (is used for striped clothing, at least in
  poetry and post-classically)
- [**Virgulatus**](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=virgulatus&filter=CUTF8) "striped" (seems to be very similar to *virgatus* but less
  frequent)

Both of these are from *[virga](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=virga&filter=CUTF8)* "twig", which is also used to mean "stripe" in clothing (II C).

- **Ostreatus** (striped or ridged like an oyster shell: doesn't seem to be used to describe a pattern in clothing)
- **Striatus** (more like furrowed, from *stria* "furrow": doesn't seem to be used for clothing)

Comment: Isn't -ul- some kind of diminutive suffix? "virgulatus" would then mean having narrow stripes, or maybe pinstripes

Comment: @Wilson: It is true that *-ul-* is a diminutive suffix, but, like diminutive suffixes in other languages, I believe it can also be used non-diminutively. I don't know why or when. The OLD has this: https://i.imgur.com/WbFyDg8.png (*-ulus* forms (1) diminutives; (2) adjectives denoting repeated action; (3) instruments). So I'm not sure about that attractive hypothesis of yours...could be!

Answer (score 6):

From biological Latin, I would suggest **striātus, -a, -um**. While it literally means "fluted" or "furrowed", it's is the word I've most often seen for "striped" in scientific names: for example, the "striped pondweed" is *Stuckenia striata*, the "striped bladderwort" is *Utricularia striata*, and the "striped snakehead" (a type of fish) is *Channa striata*.

Answer (score 6):

The most common words I have found for *striped* are *virgatus*, *varius*, and *striatus*, used for all sorts of stripes including those on clothing.  But this is only what others have already posted.

My small contribution, then, is to address your question specifically about *clavus*, or rather ***clavatus***.  I have found one reference in which this is used unambiguously for stripes on material yet which does not seem to be linked to the purple stripes of consuls etc.

> *uxorem gemmis uti non est passus. auro clavatis vestibus idem
>   interdixit.*
>
> He did not permit his wife to use jewels and also forbade her to wear
>   garments with gold stripes.

*Historia Augusta*, Tacitus, 11

Comment: If *striped* is intended to mean "with a stripe along the rim of the garment", I think *clavatus* would work! It is from *claudo* "to close (off)", so I believe it generally denotes one (big) stripe along the edge.

Comment: Then again, the final sense of the noun *clavus* gives this (L&S): *"2. Poet., a tunic, in gen., either wide or narrow striped: "mutare in horas", Hor. S. 2, 7, 10: "sumere depositum", id. ib. 1, 6, 25.*"

Answer (score 3):

On top of others already suggested (particularly *virgatus*), the 2016 OLD also suggests *maculosus*:

> (of animals, etc) Variegated, spotted, or striped.

(etc not including minerals, listed later).

It also suggests *polygrammos*:

> (of a kind of jasper) Many-striped.

But this might be too specific. [Pliny the Elder](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0137:book=37:chapter=37&highlight=polygrammos) states:

> The variety of this stone [jasper] which resembles smaragdus in colour is often found with a white line running transversely through the middle; in which case it is known as "monogrammos:" when it is streaked with several lines, it is called "polygrammos."

Comment: The former comes from _macula_, "stain/streak", so I don't think I'd apply it to intentionally-dyed clothes. A _gramma_ can be a line of writing, so that could make sense, but it does seem a bit too specific.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence to be translated is from the description of the driver of a stagecoach in 'Old Christmas' by Washington Irving (pub. 1875). It begins *His waistcoat is commonly of some bright colour, striped*, and I have finally decided on something not yet put forward, but which I think fits the case fairly well:

*Subuculam variis fere coloribus claris delineatam gerit.*

I am grateful for the interest in this question, and indeed for so many sensible and interesting suggestions, which I apologise for ultimately disregarding.

Answer (score 2):

In the Corpus Christi Alea Evangelii there is a playing piece which is coloured differently. This is sometimes translated 'speckled,' sometimes 'striped.' "Now we pass the variegated man..."

> "Varium nunc transgrediamur virum . et postea Marcus in trianguli
>   primo angulo ..."

In the same description of a board game the ranks and files are called *'trames.'* A word borrowed from weaving. *Transmeo* is the verb.

> *.X. et .VIII. tramites in longitudine* 18 ranks in length.
>   *singuli per singulos tramites,* one by one across the separate ranks.

*toga alba, nigrore transmente* a white toga woven across with black.

I had misremembered *'trames;'* I thought it meant a furrow. And perhaps that would be a better metaphor:

*toga candida et nigra sulcatim.* A toga, furrowed black and white.